# Bootstrap breadcrumb not working correctly in RTL mode

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, next.js, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a [Bootstrap breadcrumb](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/breadcrumb/) inside my next.js app. when I add the sample code from the Bootstrap's documentation inside my project, the code works just fine in LTR mode, but when I try to display it in RTL using `dir="rtl"`, the breadcrumb doesn't work as expected

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav dir="rtl" aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <a href="#">Library</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">
      Data
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

so the question is that why is it behaving like this and what's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the RTL docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/rtl/#required-html) you need to load the RTL version of the library.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-+qdLaIRZfNu4cVPK/PxJJEy0B0f3Ugv8i482AKY7gwXwhaCroABd086ybrVKTa0q" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav dir="rtl" aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <a href="#">Library</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">
      Data
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```